# How to use a path with queryparams in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need my `<Error403 />` to be rendered when a url with the params "403?redirected_from=/" is passed, but instead my `<Error404 />` is rendered. I think my 404 catch-all is being used instead, but I don't understand why.

For example, when "navigate(`/403?redirected_from=${location.pathname}`);" is used, with `location.pathname` equal to `/403?redirected_from=/thing1/thing2/2023-07-24/2023-07-30`
the 404 page is rendered.

Routes.tsx:

```
export default function MyRoutes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<NavMenu />}>
          <Route path="403?redirected_from=/*" element={<Error403 />} />
          <Route path="/" element={Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior, you need to modify your route setup. The path prop in Route doesn't support query parameters, so you can't directly use `"403?redirected_from=/*"` as a path. Instead, you should use a custom route component and handle the logic inside it. Here's how you can do it:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyRoutes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<NavMenu />}>
          <Route element={<MainContent />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function MainContent() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  // Check if the URL contains the "redirected_from" query parameter with value "/"
  if (queryParams.get('redirected_from') === '/') {
    return <Error403 />;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Error404 />} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

In this updated code, we use the useLocation hook from react-router-dom to get the current location and its query parameters. Then we check if the "redirected_from" query parameter is set to "/", and if so, we render the  component. If not, we render the regular content, including the  component for the root path and the  component for any other unmatched paths.

Comment: Yeah, a little bit modified and it works.

Comment: @AvetikNersisyan thanks for the response, nothing inside `MainContent` seems to render, and when I move components up into `MyRoutes` they render fine. Have you got this syntax working?

Answer (score 0):

coworker was able to solve the issue, changing routes path from `403?redirected_from=/*` to `/403`.